# PrivateFontCollection not found Error in c# (linux)

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, .net-core

I'm using command `dotnet build` in order to build a game in the MonoGame framework in Ubuntu 20.04 using `.NET 5.0`.
It was fine in Windows, but now that I'm using it here, it gives me this error:

> error CS1069: The type name 'PrivateFontCollection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing.Text'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly. [/home/mrwoto/Ali/Programming/csharp/SAO/SAO/SAO.csproj]

So, is there anyway to resolve it? How can I add a reference to it in `.csproj` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add it from the terminal with

```
dotnet add package System.Drawing.Common
```

After this, you should be able to see something like the following in the `.csproj` file.

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="5.0.2" />
```

Please note that `dotnet add` is more than just adding some text to csproj.

*From [dotnet add package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package):*

> The dotnet add package command provides a convenient option to add a package reference to a project file. After running the command, there's a compatibility check to ensure the package is compatible with the frameworks in the project. If the check passes, a `<PackageReference>` element is added to the project file and dotnet restore is run.